# Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 Get worksheet name

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I have been looking for a way to get the first worksheet name in a spreadsheet that I have uploaded.

Now, I have found many flavors or code when it comes to using Jet 4, but I have to use Ace 12, and when I use that driver, it will never get anything about the spreadsheet.  Does anyone know a good way to pull the spreadsheet name with Ace 12?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since all of the worksheet's are listed as table names you can use the [OleDbConnection.GetOleDbSchemaTable()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbconnection.getoledbschematable.aspx) method to get a list of all worksheets in the file.  I'm not sure about the order they are returned in, but I'd expect that they are in worksheet order.

```
DataTable dt = conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(System.Data.OleDb.OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
string workSheetName = (string)dt.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"];
```